# Paring JSON object with jsonSurfer

Tags: java, android, json

I'm having the following JSON object:

"features": [

> ```
> {
>   "type": "Feature",
>   "properties": {
>     "@id": "node/643464022",
>     "historic": "memorial",
>     "image": "imagesource",
>     "memorial:addr": "address",
>     "memorial:text": "text",
>     "memorial:type": "type",
>     "memorial:website": "website",
>     "name": "First Lastname",
>     "network": "network",
>     "person:date_of_birth": "date_of_birth",
>     "pos": "A1",
>     "website": "website",
>     "@timestamp": "2015-06-15T20:39:33Z",
>     "@version": 10,
>     "@changeset": 31992980,
>     "@user": "tomtom100",
>     "@uid": 2616776
>   },
>   "geometry": {
>     "type": "Point",
>     "coordinates": [
>       6.9601819,
>       50.9455431
>     ]
>   },
>   "id": "node/643464022"
> },
> ```

Now I wanne look in the whole JSON array after a specifc coordinates, by using jsonSurfer. But when I'm using the code snippet I'm getting a error.

```
JsonSurfer jsonSurfer = JsonSurferGson.INSTANCE;
        jsonSurfer.configBuilder()
                .bind("$.features[0].geometry[?(@.coordinates=='6.9601819,50.9455431')]", new JsonPathListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onValue(Object value, ParsingContext context) {
                         System.out.println("Surfing: " +value);
                    }
                })
                .buildAndSurf(itemsJson);

        return null;
```

The error message is the following:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.android.stolpersteinear, PID: 14459
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                         Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
>                                                                                            at
>   org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recoverInline(BailErrorStrategy.java:66)
>                                                                                            at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.match(Parser.java:206)
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.exprEqualStr(JsonPathParser.java:1070)
>                                                                                            at org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.expr(JsonPathParser.java:804)
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.filter(JsonPathParser.java:726)
>                                                                                            at org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.path(JsonPathParser.java:262)
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathCompiler.compile(JsonPathCompiler.java:216)
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.SurfingConfiguration$Builder.bind(SurfingConfiguration.java:131)
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONData.fetchJsonArray(JSONData.java:44)
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONLoader.loadInBackground(JSONLoader.java:34)
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONLoader.loadInBackground(JSONLoader.java:18)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                         Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
>                                                                                            at
>   org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recoverInline(BailErrorStrategy.java:61)
>                                                                                            at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.match(Parser.java:206) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.exprEqualStr(JsonPathParser.java:1070) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.expr(JsonPathParser.java:804) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.filter(JsonPathParser.java:726) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathParser.path(JsonPathParser.java:262) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.compiler.JsonPathCompiler.compile(JsonPathCompiler.java:216) 
>                                                                                            at
>   org.jsfr.json.SurfingConfiguration$Builder.bind(SurfingConfiguration.java:131) 
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONData.fetchJsonArray(JSONData.java:44) 
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONLoader.loadInBackground(JSONLoader.java:34) 
>                                                                                            at utils.JSONLoader.loadInBackground(JSONLoader.java:18) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Something like that works perfectly:

```
JsonSurfer jsonSurfer = JsonSurferGson.INSTANCE;
        jsonSurfer.configBuilder()
                .bind("$.features[0].geometry.coordinates]", new JsonPathListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onValue(Object value, ParsingContext context) {
                         System.out.println("Surfing: " +value);
                    }
                })
                .buildAndSurf(itemsJson);

        return null;
```

Thanks,
Bjoern

Comment: I think GSON option would be better than it.

Comment: Hi everyone I contacted the maintainer directly and currently the library has a bug and don't support comparing with a JSON array. You can find the full answer here: https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer/issues/28